# Setting up a proxy on a remote server?

Tags: proxy, remote

was wondering if it's possible to set up on a proxy on a remote server. I've tried PHProxy, which is a web based browser-in-browser proxy script I could upload via FTP, but it didn't always function with scripts or flash. Would it be possible to configure my server in such a way that it allows me to proxy via my browser's connection settings? Or do you have a better alternative?

Thanks in advance!

P.S: I hope ServerFault is the right place for this kind of thing, sorry if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your server has an SSH daemon -- you can use SSH as a SOCKS proxy:

```
$ ssh -D 8080 remote.server.ip
```

Then just configure your browser to use localhost port 8080 as a SOCKS proxy, and you're done.

You can confirm proper operation by browsing to http://whatismyip.org

Comment: I haven't got shell access unfortunately. Or is that different from SSH?

Comment: And if the remote server has multiple IPs, how would you select the ip you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Is Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) installed on the remote server?

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check if it does? (Couldn't find anything in my control panel, using cPanel)

Comment: You could add mod_proxy directives and see if they work, or you could contact your hosting provider.